# $ae. javascript notation

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I am starting to learn jQuery. Looking though the MVC3 project that makes use of Awesome MVC Html helpers, I have stumbled upon a javasript code that I don't know how to understand yet:

```
 $ae.autocomplete('Requestor'
```

What is $ae is calling a jQuery autocomplete on in this case? ae isn't an element, so this isn't an id or class selector.

P.S. And while you are at it, please let me know what $. as in `$.getJSON` calls getJSON on?

Comment: What do you get if you `console.log($ae);` or `console.log(typeof($ae));` just before this line? To have to `.autocomplete()` function called on it means that it is probably a jQuery object (that may or may not contain DOM nodes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that there isn't a typo, `$ae` is a variable. Since `$` is just a javascript function you can assign the result of it to a variable, `$ae = $("#myid")`. While I don't know that $ae is definitely the result of that, the naming convention (`$` at the beginning) makes me suspect that it is.

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery, the `$` is a convenient alias for the `jQuery` object. So `$.getJSON()` is calling the `getJSON()` method of the `jQuery` object. This is pretty confusing at first, but once you get used to it it's nice and concise.

It seems like common practice in jQuery development to use a `$` to prefix variables that result from selecting things with jQuery, like this:

```
var $myList = $('.list-item');
```

The `$` is a legal character to use in variable names, so I guess it's a reminder that the object contains a jQuery wrapped set. It's a good idea to assign the results of your selections to variables if you'll use the selected items again; otherwise you're wasting resources.

In your example, the `$ae` is the equivalent of something like this:

```
$('#my-input').autocomplete('Requestor ...
```